# 2010 Stratoline S 1900 Motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, noise

When I am cruising at about 40 mph  on my motorcycle and I disengage the throttle in any gear I  have clanging noises like metal to metal very annoying plus I just had new tires front and back this all started after that any ideas ?

I might add when I pull in the clutch it seem to lessen the noise ? Could it be The throw out bearing or transmission Issue? 
Hydraulic clutch as well ....

Thanks for all opinions!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If there's an issue after getting new tires, I'd take it back to the shop which did it. They most likely did something or didn't do something which is now affecting your riding pleasure.

Comment: Thank you ! as well I edited my question Add more facts !

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a rear wheel alignment issue, which is causing the chain to drag on the sprocket during deceleration. It would lessen when you pull in the clutch. Again, this would fall directly in the camp of the shop which put the tires on your bike.

Comment: Hi thanks I called today there picking my bike up tomorrow going back to the shop ... no chain but belt driven we thought this as well or maybe a bearing ? 
I will post when they give me a update ! My bike still under warranty a blessing !